# Application called twice even though called only once from command line

Tags: python, sockets, flask, udp

I am trying to bind a UDP socket and want to receive incoming data on the same, which will be plotted on a webpage. I am using flask to manage content on webpage. My small application code is as udner:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import json
import random
import time
from datetime import datetime
import socket
from flask import Flask, Response, render_template

UDP_IP = "127.0.0.1"
UDP_PORT = 7349

application = Flask(__name__)
random.seed()  # Initialize the random number generator

sock1 = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM) # UDP
sock1.bind((UDP_IP, UDP_PORT))   # This line is giving error irrespective of UDP_PORT number
sock1.settimeout(0.5)

@application.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template('index.html')


@application.route('/chart-data')
def chart_data():
    def generate_random_data():
        while True:
            try:
                data, addr = sock1.recvfrom(1024) # buffer size is 1024 bytes
                val = random.random()  # this line to be later changed to data received
            except:
                val = 1.0
            json_data = json.dumps(
                {'time': datetime.now().strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'), 'value': val * 100})
            yield f"data:{json_data}\n\n"
            time.sleep(1)

    return Response(generate_random_data(), mimetype='text/event-stream')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    application.run(debug=True, threaded=True)
```

I am receiving error on Windows as under:

```
C:\Users\Dev\Documents\Python_Workspace>python application.py
 * Serving Flask app "application" (lazy loading)
 * Environment: production
   WARNING: This is a development server. Do not use it in a production deployment.
   Use a production WSGI server instead.
 * Debug mode: on
 * Restarting with windowsapi reloader
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Dev\Documents\Python_Workspace\application.py", line 23, in <module>
    sock1.bind((UDP_IP, UDP_PORT))
**OSError: [WinError 10048] Only one usage of each socket address (protocol/network address/port) is normally permitted**
```

I have even tried changing UDP_PORT number. Also, rebooted my PC. However, not able to get rid of this error.

Can anyone guide me on possible solution?

EDIT:
I found that issue is due to application being called twice even though I am calling the same only once from command prompt. Why is it being called twice?

Thanks.